# Intellij Maven Sidebar invisible when minimized on Mac OS

Tags: macos, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to running IntelliJ on a Mac. On Windows, it's possible to "minimize" the Maven "toolbar" to the right edge of the screen:

[image]

On my Mac, minimizing this makes the bar disappear. Why is that? How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you've toggled tool windows view (this could be done by hitting Alt twice, or by clicking most-left bottom icon):

> If you click this button, tool window bars and buttons are shown. At the same time the button, appearance toggles to show hide tool window bars. If you click the button again, the tool window bars and buttons are hidden again.

More info in [Working with Tool Windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tool-windows.html)

Comment: Thank you, the link pointed me to the button in the lower left corner. Works like a charm. thanks.